# Inkwell Onload Event

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am programming an app in Flutter, where one child is a Inkwell (located in a ListView builder).

When the page renders its widgets, I want a function to be called that sets the state of the inkwell. I don't know how to do that, and can't find any other articles on how to do it. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
                child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: genders.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                    //WANT TO CALL A FUNCTION THAT SELECTES A GENDER 
                    IMMIDIATELY ON LOAD 
                    (this page is routed to from another page and I 
                    want to save the data that the user 
                    inputted before they moved to the next page and 
                    back)
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        genders.forEach((gender) => gender.isSelected = false);
                        genders[index].isSelected = true;
                        _gender = genders[index].name;
                        if(_gender == 'Male') {
                          changeBackgroundColor(Color.fromRGBO(196,213,239,1.000));
                        } else if(_gender == 'Female') {
                          changeBackgroundColor(Color.fromRGBO(239, 196, 234, 1));
                        } else {
                          changeBackgroundColor(Color.fromRGBO(161, 203, 180, 1));
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: sign_up_page(genders[index]),
                  );
                }
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter does not work that way. In Flutter you set your state variables and the widget uses their values when it is rendered. When variables change, you call setState() to render this widget again.

You can set the initial values of your state variables in initState() method of your widget.

Comment: Alright @AndreiVolgin- so basically my gender selection gets set in the on tap event with those 3 lines of code displayed in the code snippet above. You are saying I should run those 3 lines of code in the initState() method of my main class?

Comment: You can run it in initState() to set initial values, and then run every time the values change.